# How to convert NoData values to other values for raster data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modis, ndvi, digital-image-processing, land-classification

I have a NDVI map from MODIS data for my AOI. When classified, i noticed that few of the pixels appear in " white"  color and show no value. How do i classify these pixels and attache an appropriate / logical value to these pixels?

Comment: What software are you working with? Is it possible the values are NoData and the white background of your GIS is showing up?

Comment: I am working in Arc GIS 10.1. You are right, the values are "NO DATA" and appear in white color

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spatial Analyst `Con` tool to convert NoData to another value. For example, here is a raster calculator expression:

```
Con(IsNull("inputraster"),0,"inputraster")
```

Esri has a technical article on the subject:

[How To: Convert NoData values to other values for raster data](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010059)

Comment: Alternatively, the "Reclassify" tool has an option to turn "no data" values into 0s or any other value.

Comment: Aaron, Thanks for the guidance, Actually i want to assign the pixel value of adjoining/ neighboring pixel to the " no data" pixel, i dont want to assign " 0" (zero) value to all no data pixels and want the software to do the job, i mean, i dont want to attach/ modify value of each no data pixel by selecting one by one, it should be done using some command. How to i do that ? Pl guide